# Unable to match the url of add-to-cart handler with the path ('/cart/:id') in app.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**using react-router-dom v 6**.
I'm short of the right words to word the question but the problem is that the url of addToCart handler is not finding the addToCart path in app.js. For example, when I click on a product that has id of 2, I get this error display in the console `No routes matched location "/cart/2?qty=1"` .The same applies to any other product selected.

```
function ProductScreen({}) {
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)

    const history = useNavigate()
    const match = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
    const {error, loading, product} = productDetails

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listProductDetails(match.id))
    }, [dispatch, match])

    const addToCartHandler = () =>{
        history(`/cart/${match.id}?qty=${qty}`)
    }
    return(
        <Button onClick={addToCartHandler} Add To Cart </Button>
    )
}
```

CartScreen

```
const CartScreen = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { search } = useLocation();
    const [searchParms] = useSearchParams();
  
    const productId = id;
    const qty = search ? Number(search.split("=")[1]) : 1;
  

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
      if (productId){
        dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty))
      }
    
    }, [dispatch, productId, qty])

    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Add to CART</h1>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default CartScreen
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen/>} />
        <Route path='/cart/:id' element={<CartScreen/>} />
        <Route path='/cart/' element={<CartScreen/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Changing `<Route path='/cart/:id' element={<CartScreen/>} />` to `<Route path='/cart/:id?' element={<CartScreen/>} />` does not fix the issue. Note the difference in these two routes I tested is the `?` in the path of the second route.

Comment: What is the "addToCart" path in `App`, there's only the one route? Where is `ProductScreen` rendered that is trying to link to the `"/cart/:id"` path?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unable-to-match-the-url-of-add-to-cart-handler-with-the-path-cart-id-in-ap-3cu8n?file=/src/App.js)?

Comment: Yes @Draw Reese. What you did in codesandbox is what I'm trying to achieve. I have updated the post to include the productScreen route. I still don't get what you did to make it work like that in codesandbox

Comment: Dunno....? Does your *exact* code in a codesandbox run/work the same as it does locally on your machine? Maybe try killing any running code watchers/hot-reloaders and fully clearing any browser caches, maybe even fully close out/reopen the browser, and then run your builds again. Try running them in an incognito window.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I restarted the pc and tried it and everything worked as expected. You code copy the code the the answer section

Comment: Cool, glad it's working now. I didn't quite understand that last part though.

Comment: Sorry, that's due to the error in my grammar. What I was trying to say is you should take that comment (where you spoke of hot reload) to the answer section so that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code snippets copy/pasted into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unable-to-match-the-url-of-add-to-cart-handler-with-the-path-cart-id-in-ap-3cu8n?file=/src/App.js) that is working, but the same exact code isn't working locally for you and you're still seeing an invariant error `No routes matched location "/cart/2?qty=1"` I suggest doing a full restart. The path `"/cart/2"` should certainly be matched.

Debugging/troubleshooting steps I typically take:

- Killing any running code watchers/hot-reloaders, and fully clear browser caches, then restart development build (`npm start`)
- Fully close out/reopen the browser, and then run your
  builds again
- Try running them in an incognito window
- Reboot the machine you're running the code on

Answer (score 0):

const qty = search ? Number(search.split("=")[1]) : 1;

replace this

let qty = location.search ? Number(search.split("=")[1]) : 1;

then productID with id

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done:

use useNavigate In product screen

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
```

then the handler

```
const addToCartHandler = () => {
        navigate(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`)
    }
```

In the app.js file add the route as :

```
<Route path='/cart/:id?' element={<CartScreen />} />
```

This should help

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Image,
  ListGroup,
  Card,
  Button,
  ListGroupItem,
  Form,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import { listProductDetails } from "../actions/productActions";

// import products from "../products";
// console.log(products)
const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const { id } = useParams();

 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProductDetails(id));
   
  }, [dispatch, id]);
  
  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    navigate(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`);
  }

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, product } = productDetails;
  // console.log(loading, product);
  return (
    <>
      {loading === false ? (
        <div>
          <Link className="btn btn-dark my-3" to="/">
            Go Back
          </Link>

          <Row>
            <Col md={6}>
              <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid></Image>
            </Col>
            <Col md={3}>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroupItem>
                  <Rating
                    value={product.rating}
                    text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                  />
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>Price:${product.price}</ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem>Description:{product.description}</ListGroupItem>
              </ListGroup>
            </Col>
            <Col md={3}>
              <Card>
                <ListGroup variant="flush">
                  <ListGroupItem>
                    <Row>
                      <Col>Price</Col>
                      <Col>
                        <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroupItem>
                  <ListGroupItem>
                    <Row>
                      <Col>Status:</Col>
                      <Col>
                        {product.countInStock > 0 ? `In Stock` : `Out of Stock`}
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroupItem>
                  {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                    <ListGroupItem>
                      <Row>
                        <Col>Qty</Col>
                        <Col>
                          <Form.Control
                            as="select"
                            value={qty}
                            onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
                          >
                            {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map(
                              (x) => (
                                <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                                  {x + 1}
                                </option>
                              )
                            )}
                          </Form.Control>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </ListGroupItem>
                  )}
                  <ListGroupItem>
                    <Button
                      onClick={addToCartHandler}
                      className="btn-block "
                      type="button"
                      disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                    >
                      ADD To Cart
                    </Button>
                  </ListGroupItem>
                </ListGroup>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Please wait....</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).